# Can there be singular subtensors in the elasticity tensor and what would it mean in that case?

Tags: singularities, elasticity, stress-strain, matrix-elements

Can the elastic tensor $C_{ijkl}$ describing the stress strain relationship as
$$\sigma_{ij} = C_{ijkl} \, \varepsilon_{kl}$$
contain singular subtensors? In that case, what would it mean mechanically?

This question does not necessarily require that the elastic tensor has been reduced to 36 or fewer elements. The material may twist so $C_{ijkl} \ne C_{ijlk}$.

A similar question is: Are there any two or more different strains that cause the same stress?

Comment: [1 1;1 1] is singular. Why would it be a problem to have this submatrix appear in the stiffness tensor?

Comment: @Chemomechanics Where does it occur? I am trying to ask if there are different strain combinations that give the same stress combinations, which would not be invertible in that case = singular.

Comment: If you are talking of the 6 by 6 representation of the tensor, yes you can. The whole axial/shear block is a 3 by 3 matrix full with 0.

Comment: @nicoguaro I have to improve the question then to focus on what I mention in my first comment. I am not sure how to formulate that yet.

Comment: @nicoguaro I am considering the full 3*3*3*3 matrix.

Comment: In the case of isotropic materials you have the linear combination of the two isotropic tensors in that space. So, yes, you might have "submatrices" that are singular.

Comment: @nicoguaro Can you show that example as one possible answer? A deformation of that kind cannot fully restore to its original and thus not be fully elastic, right? In your example please show deformation and redeformation(s).

Comment: I'm just talking about the stiffness tensor, not about deformations. I think that you are missing things. It might be good if you refactor your question with what you are looking for.